# Accidentally removed pbcopy

Tags: macos

I messed up pbcopy. Instead of

```
 cat foo | pbcopy
```

I did

```
  cat foo > pbcopy
```

And now my pbcopy is a text file. How can I reinstall it? Is it a part of some specific package, maybe something in homebrew?

Comment: What OS do you have? I could just put mine up on Dropbox. I do run 10.8.5 and 10.7.4 so not the latest OS version though. Oh, you really where in /usr/bin directory at the time running that command?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you ran these commands in the directory `/usr/bin`, and with root privileges, you have not overwritten the real pbcopy - you've simply created a new file in your current working directory with the same name.

So - you most likely do not have to reinstall pbcopy. To verify, you can call the full program explicitly, like this:

```
cat foo | /usr/bin/pbcopy
```

which should work properly. If it does, you can delete the pbcopy you inadvertently created safely...

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I was root at that time...

Comment: @Adrian Ouch. Next time you are heading into root, you can issue `tmutil snapshot` to set a local snapshot of files if you have a local Time Machine destination. It won't help you now unless you already have a backup, but it's nice to have a rollback safety net when you are root.

Comment: → Adrian: if you were `root` but not within the `/usr/bin` directory, the analysis of Scot stands. I advise you to check it.

Answer (score 0):

The `pbcopy` binary comes from the OS X base installation and you can restore it from Time Machine (either a local snapshot or an external drive) will have copies of that file.

Next, you could open the installer in a program like [Pacifist](http://charlessoft.com) and extract that binary.

Worst case, rerun the installer or get a copy of the binary from a trusted source and you should be good to go as long as the source is the same level as your OS.